# Android OnChronometerTickListener not being called

Tags: android

I'm creating a simple application that uses a timer in a service. The service will then publish its time updates to the main activity.

I've decided to use a Chronometer to implement the stopwatch functionality, however when I try to get the onChronometerTick updates to update the activity, no ticks are being caught. The OnChronometerTick function is only being called once at initialisation, never again there after.

Method to init Chronometer:

```
Chronometer timer;

   @Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "TimerService created");

    // Initialise timer but don't start it
    timer = new Chronometer(this);

}

    public void startTimer() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Timer started");
    timer.setOnChronometerTickListener(listener);
    timer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
    timer.start();

}
```

where listener is:

```
    Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener listener = new Chronometer.OnChronometerTickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onChronometerTick(Chronometer chronometer) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "TICK");
        //final long time = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - timer.getBase();
        //i.putExtra(INTENT_KEY, time);
        //sendBroadcast(i);
    }
};
```

"TICK" only gets logged **once** when I call startTimer(). I have another function getElapsedTime() which calculates the elapsed time, which seems to be working fine. There are no errors or anything unusual being logged, unfortunately.

Thanks for your time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Chronometer` is a `View`, that is, a UI element. You never add your `Chronometer` to any layout, I guess that's why it's never updating.

From this `Log.d(LOG_TAG, "TimerService created");` I'm guessing you're working on a `Service` rather than an `Activity` and services don't usually have a UI, so a `Chronometer` is probably not what you want.

You could try using a `CountDownTimer` or a `Handler` / `Runnable` combination.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html

Here's an example using `Handler` / `Runnable`, I've even thrown in a `stopTimer()` method for good measure:

```
private Handler timerHandler;
private Runnable timerRunnable;

// ...

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "TimerService created");
    timerHandler = new Handler();
    timerRunnable = new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "TICK"); 
            timerHandler.postDelayed(timerRunnable, 1000);
        }
    };
}

public void startTimer() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Timer started");
    timerHandler.post(timerRunnable);
}

public void stopTimer() {
    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Timer stopped");
    timerHandler.removeCallbacks(timerRunnable);
}
```

Comment: Hey and thanks for the response. I'm looking to count up, however it seems much easier to implement using a Chronometer than a CountDownTimer.

Comment: @Panky_ham It's curious how you figure using a Chronometer is easier, considering it isn't actually working for you. See my updated answer for an alternative solution using a `Handler`.

Comment: Apologies, I just meant in the argument of CountDownTimer vs Chronometer. I looked at implementations of CountUpTimers and they seem over the top. I recently took a look at doing it with Handler/Runnable and the method you have just described confirms it. Thanks for your time and help! :)

Comment: looks nice, I really like this solution, but in my case, TICK appears only once, like if handler couldnt call timeRunnable after 1000ms...

Comment: @Marek we would probably need to see your code, which would mean, a new question. For starters, the Handler doesn't run on it's own thread, so you have to take into account the Activity/Service lifecycle.

Comment: @Marek ignore my comment about the lifecycle, just checked that up and it seems incorrect. Still we'd need to see some code to find out why it's not working.